# Grails 1.2.5/AJAX: How to force the use of jQuery instead of Prototype?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

if i ever write an

```
${remoteFunction(...)}
```

the library prototype is used - but we dont like to use prototype, we like to use jQuery!

How can i force to use ajax using jQuery? Is the use of jQuery acutally implemented in remoteFunction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Grails version prior to 1.4 see [this](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery)

From v1.4M1 Grails uses by default jQuery.

Comment: Iv found this page before, but it doesnt work for me. I use some templates, may i displaced my <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>?

Comment: I am using it w/o problems in grails 1.3.7. Have you added grails.views.javascript.library="jquery" in your config.groovy?

Comment: neither grails.views.javascript.library="jquery" nor g:javascript works. Any sugesstions?

Comment: google codesearch sais: prototype, dojo and yahoo does, jquery doesnt.

Comment: Here is what works for me: <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/> in the layout gsp and grails.views.javascript.library="jquery" in config.groovy